# Using custom blueprint cannot reach internal registry with internal CA

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-blueprint

I have not seen this discussed yet.

I'm developing a new blueprint. However, during execution of jhipster --blueprints my-blueprint it fails on the prompt

```bash
Would you like to install other generators from the JHipster Marketplace? [y/N] y 
WARNING! Unable to contact server to fetch additional modules: self signed certificate in certificate chain
```

I have `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` set for our internal cert. I've tried explicitly setting it, e.g., `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=path/to/cert.cer jhipster --blueprints my-blueprint`. It still fails.

Anyone seen this and solved?

Comment: Does cert.cer include the full CA chain?

Comment: i'll confirm. thanks.